# QR code image slow down website - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, qr-code

I am making qr code at once 1000. Its not a problem if it takes time. . I keep an URL in qrcode table. And i retrieve qrcode image without saving into database. I am using [Simple QRcode](https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode) Laravel library to generate qr code. My problem when i trying to get qrcode then website slow down because of huge amount of qrcode is retrieve & generate at a time. How can i keep qr code into database so that when i retrieve it then i will just retrieve image from database. Thanks in advance.

**My Blade view:**

```
@foreach($qrcodes as $qrcode)
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate($redirectedPage.$qrcode->id)) !!} "> </td>
        <td> <a href="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate($redirectedPage.$qrcode->id)) !!} " class="btn btn-primary" download>{{ trans('common.download_button') }}</a> </td>
    </tr>                            
@endforeach
```

Comment: I think that what you are looking for is Lazy Loading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading If you don't want to code your own solution you can achieve it by using this jquery plugin http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/

Comment: Is it possible create an image and uploads it at a time in Laravel/PHP?

Comment: Yes of course, pass your Qr's to `Storage::put()` method as docs suggest https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files it acepts multiple sources

Comment: The main thing is that i have an input field and submitted button. When i submit then it will a QR code. So now i want when i submitted then QR code will be created and at a time file path will insert into database. So that i can retrieve file path from database and show the qr code without any hassle.